# Why does print work while file.write gets stuck in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, string-formatting

I'm trying to print some data to a file, when I do:

```
print("Epoch:", '%02d' % (epoch + 1),
                      "Step:", '%04d' % (step + 1), " loss=",
                      "{:.9f}".format(average_loss), " accuracy=",
                      "{:.4f}".format(average_acc))
```

it works just fine, but:

```
file.write("Epoch:", '%02d' % (epoch + 1),
                      "Step:", '%04d' % (step + 1), " loss=",
                      "{:.9f}".format(average_loss), " accuracy=",
                      "{:.4f}".format(average_acc))
```

gets the script stuck.
I do have some other `file.write`'s to the same file, earlier in the script and they work. It seems that just this one gets it stuck. Why is that?

Comment: What does "get stuck" mean?

Comment: passing multiple arguments in a `print` statement is ok, but from where did you take it that you could pass multiple arguments to `write`?

Answer (score 1):

`print` accepts multiple arguments and prints all of them.
`io.TextIOBase.write` (or compatible methods) accept exactly one argument and should raise an error if you pass more than one.

You'll have to pass *one string*, e.g.:

```
file.write('Epoch: %02d' % (epoch + 1) +
           'Step: %04d' % (step + 1) + 
           'loss={:.9f}'.format(average_loss) +
           'accuracy={:.4f}'.format(average_acc))
```

(Preferably collapse that into a single `format` expression…)

Answer (score 1):

Because the `print` statement takes multiple arguments. It then makes a single `str` by joining those arguments with the `sep` parameter (`space` by default). But `file.write()` requires single string. You need to pass a single string. Use the `str.format()` method to make those multiple `str` parameters into a single one; then try. E.g:

```
>>> content = 'Epoch: {:02} Step: {:04} loss={:.9f} accuracy={:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, step + 1, average_loss, average_acc)
>>> file.write(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print) accept a `file=` keyword argument.

You may use

```
print("Epoch:", '%02d' % (epoch + 1),
                      "Step:", '%04d' % (step + 1), " loss=",
                      "{:.9f}".format(average_loss), " accuracy=",
                      "{:.4f}".format(average_acc),
                      file=file)
```